# GRUB error: no loaded kernel

Tags: grub2, kernel, updates, live-cd

I'm quite new to Linux, so please bear with me. On my pc I had installed Windows 7 and Ubuntu 9.04, I then switched to Kubuntu 10.x, and yesterday I installed the new main update 11.x and I left the computer to finish installing, when I came back in a few hours I saw that my monitor was blank and looked as though it was unplugged, I  checked all the cables, tried moving the mouse, pressing keyboard, still nothing, but as I said the monitor looked as though it was unplugged. Thus I pressed the reset button on my computer, the monitor started working as normally, but I can't boot into windows or Kubuntu.

This is all I can see on the screen:
GNU GRUB version 1.97 beta 4
[Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device/file completions.]

I don't have live CD to repair it using CD. Is maybe there any other way? If not, how should I repair it using CD once I'll have it with me? Also is it possible to repair it or will I have to format the partition? If I should format, which partition, only the Linux one, and Windows 7 can remain the way they were?

Thank you for all your help and ideas.

Comment: Can you clarify - did you do a fresh install overwriting your previous installation, or did you try to force an upgrade from 10.04 to 11.04?  You say that you dont have a live CD - its not clear how you did the installation.

Comment: I updated to 11.04 using update manager or how is that called. It notified me that a new stable release is available and I decided to do the upgrade, I just clicked upgrade or something similar. I made the same (also in the same way) upgrade successfully (on a cumputer in my flat) on a virtual kubuntu installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled with the live cd (Kubuntu 10.10) and the same problem occurred, again I repeated the whole thing and once again the same problem occurred. It seems that it freezes if you leave it unattended for too long, thus I tried once again, but this time I was not absent and it succeeded. But I lost all the data, well I didn't have anything really important on the Kubuntu partition, so it's no big deal.

So if anyone has the same problems, just try to install and be around all the time.